# Avoiding the return of multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: reserva, cliente, estancia

```
reserva
___________
id
id_cliente
entrada
salida
...

cliente
__________
id
nombre
apellidos
telefono
dni
....

estancia
__________
id
id_cliente
id_reserva
```

Where cliente and reserva has a 1 to 1 relation. currently I use this query.

```
SELECT r.id as rid,
       r.entrada as rentrada,
       r.salida as rsalida,
       c.nombre as cnombre,
       c.telefono as ctelefono,
       c.dni as cdni,
       c.apellidos as capellido
FROM reserva r INNER JOIN
     cliente c 
     ON r.id_mainclient = c.id
ORDER BY rid DESC
```

And I need to add `estancia`, which has a n to 1 relation with `reserva`.
What I need is maybe use `group_concat()` so I can still get all `id_clientes` in `estancia` without duplicating rows, but concatenating them instead.

Comment: Can you show what your desired output would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use group_concat using group by

```
  SELECT r.id as rid
    , r.entrada as rentrada
    , r.salida as rsalida
    , c.nombre as cnombre
    , c.telefono as ctelefono
    , c.dni as cdni
    , c.apellidos as capellido
    , group_concat(e.id_cliente)
  FROM reserva r 
  INNER JOIN cliente c on r.id_mainclient = c.id 
  INNER JOIN estancia e on r.id = e.id_reserva
  GROUP BY r.id
  ORDER BY rid DESC
```

or  using a proper separator and order by

```
SELECT r.id as rid
, r.entrada as rentrada
, r.salida as rsalida
, c.nombre as cnombre
, c.telefono as ctelefono
, c.dni as cdni
, c.apellidos as capellido
, group_concat(e.id_cliente ORDER BY e.id_cliente ASC SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM reserva r 
INNER JOIN cliente c on r.id_mainclient = c.id 
INNER JOIN estancia e on r.id = e.id_reserva
GROUP BY r.id
ORDER BY rid DESC
```

or if you need  also c.dni

```
  SELECT r.id as rid
    , r.entrada as rentrada
    , r.salida as rsalida
    , c.nombre as cnombre
    , c.telefono as ctelefono
    , c.dni as cdni
    , c.apellidos as capellido
    , group_concat(e.id_cliente ORDER BY e.id_cliente ASC SEPARATOR ' ')
    , group_concat(c.dni   SEPARATOR ' ')
  FROM reserva r 
  INNER JOIN cliente c on r.id_mainclient = c.id 
  INNER JOIN estancia e on r.id = e.id_reserva
  GROUP BY r.id
  ORDER BY rid DESC
```

Comment: from that query you got, instead of the id_cliente, can I get c.dni? (knowing that id_cliente=c.id)

Comment: explain better  .. i don't see any id_cliente  .. c.id and r.id_mainclient ... you mean cliente.id ??

Comment: group_concat(e.id_cliente) that id_cliente you got me in the firstplace, instead of that, something like: group_concat(SELECT dni from cliente cl where cl.id=e.id_cliente)

Comment: you have id_cliente in estancia  .. so  why you want group_concat  a value from a table that is not 1 to N  .. but 1 To 1 as dni from cliente  ..  (dni. from cliente should be always the same   ... anyway  .. try and chek the result  .. ..

Comment: because the value I truly need is cliente.dni

Comment: but if "cliente and reserva has a 1 to 1 relation."  .. then client.dni don't change ..you should obtain the same value reapeat

Comment: oh, but I need dni from each of estancia-id_cliente, which is 1 to n. Your first approach left me with a list of estancia.id_cliente concatenated, is there a way to change that to a select?

Comment: I don't understand you question in comment  .. you should add  a new (separated) question  .. properly described with a clear data sample and the real and complete expected  result. .. when you have posted  the new question  .. eventually comment me the new link  ..

Comment: That concat is not what I want. the first group_concat got a list of different e.id:cliente, which is the same as c.id. so I have a list of cliente.id, but I don't want cliente.id, I want to use that to get cliente.dni from each of cliente.id

Comment: i don't undertand  .. ..as  suggested ..  add  a (clear) data sample and the expected  result  ..